# value split is not a member of (String, String, String, String, String)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given is data by joining two tables.

```
joinDataRdd.take(5).foreach(println)
(41234,((102921,249,2,109.94,54.97),(2014-04-04 00:00:00.0,3182,PENDING_PAYMENT)))
(65722,((164249,365,2,119.98,59.99),(2014-05-23 00:00:00.0,4077,COMPLETE)))
(65722,((164250,730,5,400.0,80.0),(2014-05-23 00:00:00.0,4077,COMPLETE)))
(65722,((164251,1004,1,399.98,399.98),(2014-05-23 00:00:00.0,4077,COMPLETE)))
(65722,((164252,627,5,199.95,39.99),(2014-05-23 00:00:00.0,4077,COMPLETE)))
```

When I am trying to get following 
 val data = joinDataRdd.map(x=>(x._1,x._2._1.split(",")(3)))

It's is throwing an error :
value split is not a member of (String, String, String, String, String)

Answer (score 1):

```
val data = joinDataRdd.map(x=>(x._1,x._2._1._1.split(",")(3)))
```

You are trying to split the tuple so that is why the error message. At the given position `x._2._1` , 
(41234,(**(102921,249,2,109.94,54.97)**,(2014-04-04 00:00:00.0,3182,PENDING_PAYMENT))), the highlighted data is the result. So if you are looking to dig inside the tuple, then you need to advance one position.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the values are already in a tuple, so you don't need to split the string. Is

```
val data = joinDataRdd.map(x=>(x._1,x._2._1._4))
```

what you are looking for?

Comment: It is not an array, but a tuple, so it's `x._2._1._4`

Comment: Thanks, Cyrille Corpet